# Exit Code and Command Chaining

Tags: powershell

If I have chained a bunch of commands together like:

```
$time_elapsed = (Measure-Command{Import-VM -Copy -GenerateNewId -Path $Path_name | Out-Host}).TotalMinutes
```

Which command's status does $? hold?

Is it Measure-Command?  Import-VM?  or Measure-Command.TotalMinutes?

Comment: For what it is worth, I think this is purely an academic question as `$?` doesn't give any information as to which operation in the last statement set the status. In this example any of the three could throw an exception and the result would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation under [`help about_Automatic_Variables`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) the definition for the `$?` variable is as follows:

> Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.

So what is considered an operation in PowerShell? I couldn't find a definitive answer - so I am going to use an unofficial one until it can be clarified: An operation is a cmdlet being invoked or the evaluation of an expression such as usage of an operator and literal values.

With that in mind, I count at least four operations in your statement:

- Measure-Command
- Import-VM
- Out-Host
- Assigning TotalMinutes to $time_elapsed

Any of those four could cause the current statement to terminate - hopefully normally but certainly any could throw an exception for example. With that in mind, I don't think you could always determine which of the operations of a statement caused the value in `$?` to be set.